# How does R deal with special characters in regulars expressions?

Tags: regex, r

I'm puzzled by the output of the 3 following test :

This one includes a special character « ° » and gives the good outcome :

```
sub(pattern = ".*([[:digit:]]{5}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = "A°C 01160")
[1] "01160"
```

This one includes a quote and gives the the good outcome :

```
sub(pattern = ".*([[:digit:]]{5}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = "01160 'aa")
[1] "01160"
```

But this one includes ° and a quote and return a weird outcome

```
sub(pattern = ".*([[:digit:]]{5}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = "A°C 01160 'aa")
[1] "0 'aa"
```

By the way, I'm also puzzled by the fact that the outcome isn't the same if I give the same input as a vector :

```
sub(pattern = ".*([[:digit:]]{5}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = c("A°C 01160", "01160 'aa", "A°C 01160 'aa"))
[1] "01160" "0 'aa" "0 'aa"
```

Does anyone has a clue to understand the origin of my problem ?

I run R 3.02 on Mac OS 10.8 with French UTF-8 encoding options :

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/C/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: I tried your code but get a "good" result in all cases.  Your example doesn't seem to be replicable.  What version of R are you using?  Please post the result of `sessionInfo()` into your question.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this in R 3.1.0 and OS X 10.9.2 in an English UTF-8 locale.

Comment: Note that this issue is specifically to do with whether you have a `°` anywhere in your string. It is also specific to using a predefined character class and can be prevented by setting either `perl` or `setBytes` to TRUE. No idea what the issue is caused by though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not completely defined by your tests. The problem is specifically to do with the `°` character and all other special UTF characters e.g. `Ĉ` also causes the same issue.

The strange ouput, given your input pattern, is actually always the last five characters of your input string. So, adding another character on to your initial "good" test will show that that test is also giving an incorrect result:

```
sub(pattern = ".*([[:digit:]]{5}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = "A°C 01160a")
[1] "1160a"
```

The quote doesn't contribute to the problem and is a red herring. Using `perl=TRUE` or `useBytes=TRUE` also prevents the issue from occurring.

I think the issue is related to the following excerpt from ?regexp:

```
 In UTF-8 mode the named character classes only match ASCII
 characters
```

So predefined character classes might not correctly process UTF-8 text. In this case, `[0-9]` instead of `[[:digit:]]` seems to work fine since it isn't a predefined class.

I still don't quite know what causes the specific output of the last 5 characters, though. My guess is that the predefined classes are matching everything when the string is UTF-8 encoded, since you can get the same output with the pattern `".*(.{5}).*"`. But at least we have a better idea of what the issue is exactly: predefined character classes processing UTF-8 character sets.

Comment: It's actually pertains to the current locale.  That's it.

Answer (score 4):

Interpretation of named character classes like including `[:digit:]` depends upon the locale in question.  They can encompass non-ASCII characters.

`[[:digit:]]` would match any character in the Unicode *Nd* category.

If you want to match only ASCII-decimal digits, use `[0-9]`.

```
> sub(pattern = ".*([[:digit:]]{5}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = "A°C 01160 'aa")
[1] "0 'aa"
> sub(pattern = ".*([0-9]{5}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = "A°C 01160 'aa")
[1] "01160"
>
```

Moreover, your observation isn't really specific to `R`.  Quoting from [regex](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html):

> Certain named classes of characters are predefined. Their
>   interpretation depends on the *locale* (see [locales](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html)); the interpretation
>   below is that of the POSIX locale.

---

EDIT: Demo of what has been mentioned above:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
> sub(pattern = ".*([[:digit:]]{5}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = "A°C 01160 'aa")
[1] "0 'aa"
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C") 
[1] "LC_CTYPE=C;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
> sub(pattern = ".*([[:digit:]]{5}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = "A°C 01160 'aa")
[1] "01160"
>
```

To elaborate on the demo, the same substitution returned different results for different locales.  The result was *as expected* when switching to `C` locale.

Comment: Unicode Nd does not include, for example, `aa` which is seemingly matched by `[[:digit:]]` in the examples. So that wouldn't completely explain the observed output unless I am missing something...

Answer (score 2):

Try using `perl = TRUE`:

```
> sub(pattern = ".*([[:digit:]]{5}).*", replacement = "\\1", 
      x = "A°C 01160 'aa",perl = TRUE)
[1] "01160"
```

Seems to work for the other version, too:

```
> sub(pattern = ".*([[:digit:]]{5}).*", replacement = "\\1", 
    x = c("A°C 01160", "01160 'aa", "A°C 01160 'aa"),perl = TRUE)
[1] "01160" "01160" "01160"
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but it doesn't explain why the other version fails.

Comment: Workarounds are great and all, but I thought the question was more "why does this happen?"

Comment: @Mattrition <shrug> I contribute what I can.